# why does expression blend open the solution

Tags: expression-blend

I browse to a single project in my solution that I want to open and expression blend opens the entire solution instead.  Any way to avoid this?

Comment: So you're saying that you have multiple projects in your solution, and you want to open only one project?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have a solution that builds in VS2010, but not in Blend (when I try to open it in Blend 4 it all collapses as Blend can't find... well anything). I thought I'd try to just open the SL project within my solution, and _all_ the projects appear.

Edit: Just discovered there's a service pack for Blend 4 (hopefully with Sketchflow). I'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Retne Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: 6 years later... no. But it's not such an issue for me any more :) !

Answer (score 1):

Expression Blend  and Visual Studio share the same .sln and csproj/vbproj formats.  Visual Studio always opens a solution file at the same time that it opens the project file.  If VS can find a related sln file, then it opens that one in conjunction with the project file.  I assume Blend works the same way.  So in your case, that means all the associated projects are loaded too.

If VS cannot find a matching sln file, then it creates an empty solution and adds your project.  That's why you sometimes get prompted to save a solution, when closing VS/Blend.

-- Yes, I see this is an old question... but still worth answering I think.